# Silverlight Navigation: How to remember page state?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm not sure how to preserve page state in Silverlight 4.

I have a page called `SearchPage`. The user comes to it with a query, but the query may change while the user is there. If the user goes back, I'd like the most recent version of the query to be retained, not the original one.

To do this, I overrode `OnFavigatedFrom()` and changed `NavigationContext.QueryString` to reflect the new values. Then, in `OnNavigatedTo()`, I check for those values.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It appears that I can't change the query string, because when I call `navigator.GoBack()`, it goes back to the original query string.

What other way can I preserve page state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the NavigationCacheMode property on the Page to Enabled or Required, which will cache and retain the page's state when it's navigated away from.